# "show/hide" - "load/unload" - iframes, div tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am sorry for my questions, but I am a beginner...

I need a javascript that allows me to:

1 "load/unload" a webpage within an "iframe" (or something similar).
2 "show/unshow" different "div tags"

when i click on a "menu link".

That means that i need a "menu" with different "links" and when I click on one of them, an "iframe" will be loaded and different "div tags" with the same id will be shown.
If then I click on another "menu link", I need the first "iframe" to "unload", all the first "div tags" to "hide", another "iframe" to be "loaded" and other "div tags" to be shown.

The thing is, that if I have a script that hides/shows "iframes", all of them are loaded when the page is opened, and all the videos and music on the different pages will autostart...

Thank you!!!

```
  <!-- this is the menu link tag -->
  <a href="#/google" onclick="">google</a>

  <!-- this tag should be shown on menu link click -->
  <a href="http://www.google.com/" target="_blank">www.google.com/</a>

  <!-- this iframe should be loaded on menu link click -->
  <iframe src="https://www.google.com/">iframe not supported</iframe>
```

Comment: Please add some sample code (or a http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: hi, i added a code... cheers

Answer (score 0):

Well that won't be `iframe` since `iframe`s are loaded at the DOM load event.

To do that, you might consider using `.load()` of the jQuery API.

Like this:

```
$('element_where_load_happens').load('new_url_here');
```

This will load the `http://new_url_here` to the `element_where_load_happens`. It is easy and better to use.

Using the above code, you will be able to

#### Load the web content

In the DOM, on some specific event, lets say a `click` event. And at the same time, you can hide the content using the `hide()` method of the jQuery API, or even wipe out all the content of that element using: `html('')` method, please note the `''` in between the paranthesis to wipe out current values.

https://api.jquery.com/load/ (jQuery Load)

Comment: thank you, would it be possible to make an example on http://jsfiddle.net/ ?? cheers

Comment: @user3248501, I am sorry, this is not a freelance website! :) Hope you don't mind. Please try giving some time to learn these standards rather then asking for them...